# Converting from Avro schema to Google BigQuery schema in python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam, avro

Is there a python library that converts Avro schemas to BigQuery schemas?

I noticed that the [Java SDK for Apache Beam](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryAvroUtils.java#L206) has a utility that converts from Avro to BigQuery. However, [the python SDK for Apache Beam](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_avro_tools.py) only maps in the other direction, mapping BigQuery to Avro.

Am I missing it? Does the python Beam SDK map from Avro to BigQuery? Or is there another library out there that does that?

Comment: What do you mean with convert Avro to BQ? You mean writing an AVRO file to a BigQuery table?

Comment: I actually mean converting an avro *schema* to a bigquery schema, independent of any records. Our use case involves streaming avro with changing schemas and BigQuery's schema autodetection wasn't able to handle that.

I wound up having to write code to this myself.

Comment: @Xiphias were you able to create bq schema using a Avro schema. i could use any reference if possible.

Comment: I was - unfortunately I had to write the code myself. I am not sure if I can disclose it given that it was done for my work.

Comment: I ran into this package after checking your question (for future readers): https://pypi.org/project/avro-to-bigquery/