# BigQuery auto detect schema and create table, in case of the streaming job in apache_beam

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a stream of information coming in, want to record them in BigQuery but the problem is the user can define a new table name before starting the apache_beam job. Also the schema in stream can change overtime.

I wanted to know if anyone achieved the automatic table creation and schema change for the streaming apache_beam jobs using Python SDK

Comment: Can you use `Avro` as source data ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun, yes I can use Avro

Answer (score 0):

I am much more familiar with the Beam Java SDK, but it sounds like you want is to define your BigQuery sink with dynamic destinations, which is a concept that exists in both Java and Python SDKs: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#using-dynamic-destinations

Dynamic destinations will allow you to pull the name of the destination table out of the message itself. You'll want `create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED` to allow creation of tables. BigQuery also has a concept of `SchemaUpdateOptions` (at least for load jobs) that you may be able to control via the `additional_bq_parameters` keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it can help

- I had this need for Java :

If you use `Avro` as input data from `Pub Sub`, the `Bigquery` schema can be inferred from the `Avro` schema.

If you want to create the `Bigquery` table from the `Beam` job, you have to set this option in the `BigqueryIO` :  `create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED`

An example for `Dataflow` `Java` :

https://cloud.google.com/architecture/streaming-avro-records-into-bigquery-using-dataflow

- For `Python` :

A `Dict` can be directly sink to `Bigquery` without having to convert current element to `TableRow`.
For `TableSchema` in `Python` I didn't found an equivalent as the
`useBeamSchema` method

```
BigQueryIO.<GenericRecord>write()
        .to(bigQueryTable)
        .useBeamSchema()
        .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
        .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
        .optimizedWrites());
```

but I think the `Beam` `Bigquery` schema can be inferred automatically from the Avro schema.

If it's not the case, maybe you have to implement your own converter from `Avro` schema to `Beam` `Bigquery` schema.

`Beam` proposes util methods for schema conversions in `Java` :
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryAvroUtils.java#L206

For `Python` the util is from `Bigquery` to `Avro` but not the inverse

I also saw this topic : [Converting from Avro schema to Google BigQuery schema in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454909/converting-from-avro-schema-to-google-bigquery-schema-in-python)